# How to include a second file when clicked a link on already included file?

Tags: php

I have included my index_login.php (the file with login form on it)  to my index.php, and when I click to [Log In] it goes to login.php ( the file with checking if user exist and if exist says welcome etc.) but I want to make all login related files to be included in my index.php for easy editing of the template.
I have tried several things but so far couldn't manage to achieve it, any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Elaborate on easy editing of the template?

Comment: Not all login related files should be inside index.php, only those that are *always* needed.

Comment: TJohnW: instead of making every page look like index.php, I want to include any page to it.

Comment: Guns: What do you need to include it for? Variables you need or for the html?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just direct to the same page? And then do something like this at the top.

```
if(isset($_POST['whatever'])) {
  //process login stuff
  //redirect home and die if you want
}

//or continue execution normally
```